# Read return value of a python function ignoring the logs

Tags: java, python, jython, processbuilder, runtime.exec

I have a python function like :

```
def test:
   dict = call(name=1)
   return dict
```

Im calling it via Java as below and trying to read the dictionary it returns :

```
try {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new
            InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String ret;
    while ((ret = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println("value is : " + ret);
    }
} catch (
        Exception e)

{
}
```

Issue is, the `call(name)` function prints a bunch of logs which is coming along with my result in the inputstream. How can I avoid this and get just the result ?

Please note: 
1. Disabling logs is not an option
2. I tried formatting the return statement and then parsing the result via some regex from the input stream but that seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Is the function using the logging module?

Comment: You're getting all of the log messages because `getInputStream` will give you the standard out of the process you've started. Similarly, you can get a handle on stdin and stderr for the process. That `return dict` will _never_ reach your java code as-is. You need some way to marshal the data between your python process and your java process. There are multiple ways to do this, but probably the simplest I can think of right now is: write a result file out when the python's done (`json.dump`), and read the result in from your java.

Comment: @hearot yes it is

Comment: @wholevinski  only issue I have with the file approach is the potential performance issue as this would be part of a service which does user interaction so response times are key

Comment: @user2810114 Try with `logging.config.dictConfig({ 'version': 1, 'disable_existing_loggers': True, })`

Comment: @user2810114 Alright...well looping through stdout and doing regex matches is probably orders of magnitude slower than a simple JSON file. You have other options like direct socket communication, messaging brokers, etc, but those are all extremely over-engineered for what it seems like you're doing.

Comment: The question is tagged with "jython", but it does not seem to have anything to do with Jython.

Comment: @mzjn It could possibly have a better solution in jython that's why it's tagged with it.